# Better way to update the underlying lookup via EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Here's my situation - I've got a DB which has some tables named **recipes**, **ingredients** and **recipes_ingredients**.

Recipes are composed of 1+ ingredients.

The **recipes_ingredients** has FKs between the **recipes** and **ingredients** table.

The classes that get generated are `recipe` and `ingredient` and `recipe` has a navigation property that looks like so:

`public virtual ICollection<ingredients> ingredients { get; set; }`

Great, I understand that I get a generated `recipe` class and a generated `ingredient` class and that the `recipes_ingredients` table *doesn't* get a class generated since EF views this simply as a navigation property.

Now, I've got a function called `SetIngredientsForRecipe` that looks like so (minus the try-catch code for brevity's sake:

```
public void SetIngredientsForRecipe(long recipeId, List<string> ingredients)
{
   using (var db = new FoodEntities(ConnectionString, null, null))
   {
      var existing = GetCurrentIngredients(recipeId);
      var toRemove = existing.Except(ingredients);
      var toAdd = ingredients.Except(existing);
      var recipe = db.recipes.Where(r => r.Id == recipeId).FirstOrDefault();
      foreach (var name in toRemove)
      {
         var entry = recipe.ingredients.Where(i => i.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
         recipe.ingredients.Remove(entry);
      }
      foreach (var name in toAdd)
      {
         var entry = db.ingredients.Where(i => i.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
         recipe.ingredients.Add(entry);
      }
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

The intent, as the name suggests, is to update the ingredient list for the given recipe to only whatever is in the list.  I'm still getting comfortable with EF and wondering if there's a better (more efficient?) way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

---

**Follow-up:**

Following the suggestions by **ntziolis** below, I opted to use

`recipe.ingredients.Clear()`  to clear out whatever was in the recipe/ingredient mapping and then use the mocking that was mentioned to quickly add the new ones.  Something like this:

```
foreach (var name in ingredients)
{
  // Mock an ingredient since we just need the FK that is referenced
  // by the mapping table - the other properties don't matter since we're
  // just doing the mapping not inserting anything 

  recipe.ingredients.Add(new Ingredient()
  {
    Name = name
  });
}
```

and this works very nicely.

Comment: So an ingredient will appear in the list whether it is to be added or removed? Shouldn't you be able to figure out which action to take based on what was done in the UI (and pass in distinct lists)?

Comment: The list from the UI (the `ingredients` parameter) only has the "truth" about what should be an ingredient, regardless of what the DB currently says.  I *could* possible know this in the UI but like the simplicity of just saying "UI, tell me what's suppose to be in this recipe."  But yes, the result would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General performance guidelines are:

- try to deal with id's only
- mock entities whenever possible, rather than retrieving them from db
- use the new features of EF4 like `Contains` in order to simplify and speed up your code

Based on these principles here is a optimized (not simpler though) solution to your problem:

```
public void SetIngredientsForRecipe(long recipeId, List<string> ingredients)
{
   using (var db = new FoodEntities(ConnectionString, null, null))
   {
      var recipe = db.recipe.Single(r => r.ID == recipeId);

      // make an array since EF4 supports the contains keyword for arrays
      var ingrArr = ingredients.ToArray();

      // get the ids (and only the ids) of the new ingredients
      var ingrNew = new HasSet<int>(db.ingrediants
        .Where(i => ingrArr.Contains(i.Name))
        .Select(i => I.Id));   

      // get the ids (again only the ids) of the current receipe
      var curIngr = new HasSet<int>(db.receipes
        .Where(r => r.Id == recipeId)
        .SelectMany(r => r.ingredients)
        .Select(i => I.Id));        

      // use the build in hash set functions to get the ingredients to add / remove            
      var toAdd = ingrNew.ExpectWith(curIngr);
      var toRemove = curIngr.ExpectWith(ingrNew);   

      foreach (var id in toAdd)
      {
        // mock the ingredients rather than fetching them, for relations only the id needs to be there
        recipe.ingredients.Add(new Ingredient()
        {
          Id = id
        });
      }

      foreach (var id in toRemove)
      {
        // again mock only
        recipe.ingredients.Remove(new Ingredient()
        {
          Id = id
        });
      }

      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

If you want it simpler you could just clear all ingredients and re add them if necessary, EF might even be clever enough to figure out that the relations haven't changed, not sure about it though:

```
public void SetIngredientsForRecipe(long recipeId, List<string> ingredients)
{
  using (var db = new FoodEntities(ConnectionString, null, null))
  {    
    var recipe = db.recipe.Single(r => r.ID == recipeId);

    // clear all ingredients first
    recipe.ingredients.Clear()

    var ingrArr = ingredients.ToArray();
    var ingrIds = new HasSet<int>(db.ingrediants
      .Where(i => ingrArr.Contains(i.Name))
      .Select(i => I.Id)); 

    foreach (var id in ingrIds)
    {
      // mock the ingredients rather than fetching them, for relations only the id needs to be there
      recipe.ingredients.Add(new Ingredient()
      {
        Id = id
      });
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Some coding errors have been corrected.

Comment: Hey thanks for the ideas here.   I'm thinking about the idea of the mock.  So the idea here is that I just need the primary key part of the ingredient object so that the underlying table can be update, right?  So while my `Ingredient` class has lots of other properties, I don't care about any of those for the navigation property, just the identifier.  Interesting.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can condense your `Where` clauses with the `FirstOrDefault` calls:

```
recipe.ingredients.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name);
```

Though I personally prefer to use `SingleOrDefault` though I'm not sure what the difference is exactly:

```
recipe.ingredients.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == name);
```

Also, since the ingredient list that is passed in is a `List<string>` (as opposed to a list of ingredient IDs), it sort of implies that new ingredients may also be created as part of this process, which isn't handled (though may have been left out for brevity).

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut there.  Yeah, `FirstOrDefault` allows for multiples to exist, `SingleOrDefault` throws if there's more than one.    Since my ingredients are unique, I guess either works though I wonder if `FirstOrDefault` might be faster.  Something to look at.  As to the second part, currently ingredients are identified by unique strings rather than integer Ids.  That could change in the future, I suppose, but currently the table's built w/out an Id column.

Comment: The differen between `First` and `Single` is that `First` will iterate the sequence until an element matching the predicate is found. At that point the iteration will stop. `Single` will iterate the entire sequence and throw an exception if more than one element matches the predicate. `FirstOrDefault` and `SingleOrDefault` have similar behavior except that a default value is returned if there is no match. This makes `FirstOrDefault` more efficient but `SingleOrDefault` can be used for validation.

Comment: @itsmatt - Based on Martin's explanation, you're right `FirstOrDefault` is faster but does not guarantee a unique result from the data set.